# How to replace single-quote with double-quote in sql query - oracle 10g?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I replace single-quote (') with double-quote (") in sql query - oracle 10g?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should work:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET myField = REPLACE(myField, '''', '"');
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use Ansi-codes as well, to make it more crystal what is happening:

```
SELECT someString
      ,replace(someString, Chr(39), Chr(34)) as replacedString
FROM   (SELECT ' abc ' || Chr(39) || ' def ' as someString
        FROM   Dual)
```

39 is a single quote, 34 a double quote

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable in single quotes with an apostrophe e.g. 'John's Book', simply insert 2 apostrophes. i.e. 'John''s Book'. NOTE: Do NOT use a double quotation "

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET field = replace(your_string,Chr(39),Chr(39)||Chr(39));
```

Comment: I believe your answer is replacing a `'` with two duplicate characters (`''`). While it might looks the same, it's actually not the same character as the author asked about, which is `"` (character 34).

Answer (score -3):

Ten bucks says this thing is wide-open to SQL injection and the correct answer is to use parameterization.

Comment: This answer would have been much more helpful if you'd provided an example of parameterization. How would you use it to solve this problem?

Comment: We know nothing about the environment from which this is being called, nor the query, so there's no general example I can give that will be in any way relevant.  It's probably something called from client code and there are any number of ways to parameterize that.